# dask apply: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: python, dask

I have a dataframe of params and apply a function to each row. this function is essentially a couple of sql_queries and simple calculations on the result.

I am trying to leverage Dask's multiprocessing while keeping structure and ~ interface. The example below works and indeed has a significant boost:

```
def get_metrics(row):

    record = {'areaName': row['name'],
              'areaType': row.area_type,
              'borough': row.Borough,
              'fullDate': row['start'],
              'yearMonth': row['start'],
              }


    Q = Qsi.format(unittypes=At,
                   start_date=row['start'],
                   end_date=row['end'],
                   freq='Q',
                   area_ids=row['descendent_ids'])

    sales = _get_DF(Q)
    record['salesInventory'] = len(sales)
    record['medianAskingPrice'] = sales.price.median()
    R.append(record)

R = []
x = ddf.map_partition(lambda x: x.apply(_metric, axis=1), meta={'result': None})
    x.compute()

result2 = pd.DataFrame(R)
```

However, when I try to use `.apply` method instead (see below), it throws me `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'name'`...

```
R = list()
y = ddf.apply(_metrics, axis=1, meta={'result': None})
```

Yet, ddf.head() shows that there is a `name` column in the dataframe

Comment: You write `dask_DF.apply()` but say that `ddf` has a name column. Try `ddf.apply()`.

Comment: thanks, but that is just (resolved) misspelling, as I try to simplify the code here. It has nothing to do with the issue

Comment: The accepted answer also works for me. But the code sample in the question is too complex, and most of the code is not related to the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the output of your `_metric` function is a Series, maybe you should use `meta=('your series's columns name','output's dtype')`

This worked for me.

Comment: Could you please explain why using a tuple makes a difference here? This is not apparent from the documentation.

Comment: I'm sorry,I hadn't use dask for nearly 2 years,I guess meta parameter tell dask the part you want use and output type,maybe because if u don't set dtype,dask maybe infer an error dtpye