# dask apply function to return dataframe: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: python, python-3.x, apply, dask

Realize this will appear as a duplicate, but after reviewing [dask apply: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'name'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46737134/dask-apply-attributeerror-dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-name) I still don't have a clear idea of where my code is breaking. Below is a minimum reproducible example that I think reflects the problem I'm running into with my larger code.

```
import pandas as pd
from dask import dataframe as dd

dummy_df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [1,2,3,4,5]})

dd_dummy = dd.from_pandas(dummy_df, npartitions = 1)

"""Arbitrary function that returns dataframe, taking keyword argument from apply"""
def test(x, bleh):
    return pd.DataFrame({'test' : 7 * [bleh]})

ok = dd_dummy.apply(test, axis = 1
                , bleh = 'fish'
                , meta = {'test' : 'str'}).compute()
```

I feel like I'm following the documentation at https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.apply pretty faithfully, so not sure what's let to try here.

Error Message:

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-76aefefcffe4> in <module>()
     12 ok = dd_dummy.apply(test, axis = 1
     13                 , bleh = 'fish'
---> 14                 , meta = {'test' : 'str'}).compute()

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/base.py in compute(self, **kwargs)
    164         dask.base.compute
    165         """
--> 166         (result,) = compute(self, traverse=False, **kwargs)
    167         return result
    168 

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/base.py in compute(*args, **kwargs)
    435     keys = [x.__dask_keys__() for x in collections]
    436     postcomputes = [x.__dask_postcompute__() for x in collections]
--> 437     results = schedule(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
    438     return repack([f(r, *a) for r, (f, a) in zip(results, postcomputes)])
    439 

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/threaded.py in get(dsk, result, cache, num_workers, pool, **kwargs)
     82         get_id=_thread_get_id,
     83         pack_exception=pack_exception,
---> 84         **kwargs
     85     )
     86 

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/local.py in get_async(apply_async, num_workers, dsk, result, cache, get_id, rerun_exceptions_locally, pack_exception, raise_exception, callbacks, dumps, loads, **kwargs)
    484                         _execute_task(task, data)  # Re-execute locally
    485                     else:
--> 486                         raise_exception(exc, tb)
    487                 res, worker_id = loads(res_info)
    488                 state["cache"][key] = res

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/local.py in reraise(exc, tb)
    314     if exc.__traceback__ is not tb:
    315         raise exc.with_traceback(tb)
--> 316     raise exc
    317 
    318 

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/local.py in execute_task(key, task_info, dumps, loads, get_id, pack_exception)
    220     try:
    221         task, data = loads(task_info)
--> 222         result = _execute_task(task, data)
    223         id = get_id()
    224         result = dumps((result, id))

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/core.py in _execute_task(arg, cache, dsk)
    119         # temporaries by their reference count and can execute certain
    120         # operations in-place.
--> 121         return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))
    122     elif not ishashable(arg):
    123         return arg

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/optimization.py in __call__(self, *args)
    989         if not len(args) == len(self.inkeys):
    990             raise ValueError("Expected %d args, got %d" % (len(self.inkeys), len(args)))
--> 991         return core.get(self.dsk, self.outkey, dict(zip(self.inkeys, args)))
    992 
    993     def __reduce__(self):

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/core.py in get(dsk, out, cache)
    149     for key in toposort(dsk):
    150         task = dsk[key]
--> 151         result = _execute_task(task, cache)
    152         cache[key] = result
    153     result = _execute_task(out, cache)

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/core.py in _execute_task(arg, cache, dsk)
    119         # temporaries by their reference count and can execute certain
    120         # operations in-place.
--> 121         return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))
    122     elif not ishashable(arg):
    123         return arg

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/utils.py in apply(func, args, kwargs)
     28 def apply(func, args, kwargs=None):
     29     if kwargs:
---> 30         return func(*args, **kwargs)
     31     else:
     32         return func(*args)

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py in apply_and_enforce(*args, **kwargs)
   5141             c = meta.columns
   5142         else:
-> 5143             c = meta.name
   5144         return _rename(c, df)
   5145     return df

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5065             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5066                 return self[name]
-> 5067             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5068 
   5069     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'name'
```

I am able to get the following code to run, but it winds up returning a pd.Series object with the values of each element being pd.DataFrame objects. Unfortunately this doesn't scale in practice, but posting to offer some potential added context. I got it to work with the following replacement on the meta argument:

```
df = dd_dummy.apply(test, axis = 1
                , bleh = 'fish'
                , meta = (None, 'object').compute()
```

Then resolve to final df with:

```
df= pd.concat(df.values)
```

Thanks!

Comment: UPDATE: Found a potential solve and have answered my question below, but not sure as to why this is working so leaving open if anyone has a better explanation. Will mark as answered if not responded to in the next couple days

Comment: I can't see the answer, did you post it? Thanks

Comment: Hey @Dahn, I actually deleted the initial answer and updated it to the initial question (lower section of the above). The pd.concat(df.values) component technically runs, but after executing on the actual data set realized this isn't a viable solve (ran for about an hour and a half on ~9 mil dataframes before cancelling).